# Adding border-bottom to an li in an ol

Tags: css, border, padding, html-lists

Trying to add a border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc to an li in an ol.

I want the number of the ol to be inside the border not outside. Right now the border it not below the numbers.

I have these classes set now:

```
ol {padding:0 0 0 30px;margin:0;}
ol li {font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:#666;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding:0 0 15px;margin:0 10px 15px 0;}
```

Basically want 15px of padding around the li and the borders to be the full width of the ol.

Any direction on this would be great thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that you want to add

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

to your `ol li` or `ol` style.

Comment: There seems to be an issue in ie7 now with this css property